# How to do multi-process with shell script?

Tags: python, shell, multiprocessing

I want to write a shell script which can start two python scripts parallelly. Other commands in shell script will run after the two parallel python processes are done.

In conclusion, two key-points:

1. run the two python processes parallelly;
2. run other commands **after** the python processes are done.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare -a pids
launch_first_program &
pids+=($!)
launch_second_program &
pids+=($!)
wait "${pids[@]}"
continue_with_our_day
```

After a process is launched in background with `&`, the variable `$!` will contain the child's PID. We can collect it into an array variable, then use `wait` to block till all of the listed processes are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wait` in bash to wait for background processes to finish

`python script1.py &
python script2.py &
wait
Other commands`

Comment: A bare `wait` would wait for all background processes, including e.g. backgrounded `vim` (something that I'll pretty much always have in my environment). It may be it will work, but I'd rather be safe. :)

Comment: @Amadan, yes agreed, your solution is far more elegant. Tom